# Split a certificate string into two separate certificates

Tags: string, kotlin, split, ssl-certificate, certificate

What is the best way to get two certificates from a single certificate string

The string looks like this

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. 
Donec cursus ornare ligula ut porta. Fusce vel orci vitae 
diam faucibus euismod. Donec non elit ut mi iaculis solli
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
Suspendisse potenti. Vivamus mauris diam, fermentum sit 
amet mauris ac, maximus consequat mauris. Vivamus elementum 
iaculis lacus nec suscipit
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

What is the best way to split this into two certificates so I get

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. 
Donec cursus ornare ligula ut porta. Fusce vel orci vitae 
diam faucibus euismod. Donec non elit ut mi iaculis solli
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

and

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
Suspendisse potenti. Vivamus mauris diam, fermentum sit 
amet mauris ac, maximus consequat mauris. Vivamus elementum 
iaculis lacus nec suscipit
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

I have tried splitting by new lines and by the `-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----` and the former obviously doesn't work and the latter leaves behind data

Comment: Where do you get this certificate, is it in your resources or do you get it from a website? And is it modifiable or not?

Comment: @Mert is modifiable. I am retrieving it from a secure store/secret manager and I have to pass it to make an SSL call. Its totally modifiable as I have it in a string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below code block will solve your problem, i've tested :

```
val certificates : String = "-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE----- Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec cursus ornare ligula ut porta. Fusce vel orci vitae diam faucibus euismod. Donec non elit ut mi iaculis solli -----END CERTIFICATE----- -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE----- Suspendisse potenti. Vivamus mauris diam, fermentum sitamet mauris ac, maximus consequat mauris. Vivamus elementumiaculis lacus nec suscipit -----END CERTIFICATE-----"
        val array: List<String> = certificates.split("-----END CERTIFICATE-----")
        val firstCertificate = array[0] + "-----END CERTIFICATE-----"
        val secondCertificate = array[1] + "-----END CERTIFICATE-----"
        Log.e("firstCertificate", firstCertificate)
        Log.e("secondCertificate", secondCertificate)
```